# newConnection() signal does not get emitted in QTcpSever even when I am clearly connecting to the server

Tags: c++, qt, networking, tcp, network-programming

QTcpServer is supposed to emit the `newConnection()` signal whenever it receives a new client connection. I am able to connect to the server I created, even telnet to it. But in the server implementation, I have connected the `newConnection()` signal to a slot and it never gets invoked.

Can you please look at my code and tell me what is it that I am doing wrong ?

First the header :

```
#include <data_model.pb.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QVector>
#include <iostream>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QDebug>

class QTcpServer;
class QNetworkSession;

class superServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit superServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    data_model::terminal_data fetch_next_record();
    void route_data();

private slots:
    void sessionOpened();

public slots:
    void newTerminalConnection();
    void errorconnecting(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError);

private:
    QTcpServer *tcpServer;
    QNetworkSession *networkSession;
    QVector<QTcpSocket*> liveConnections;
};


#endif // SUPERSERVER_HPP
```

Now the implementation:

```
#include <superServer.hpp>

void superServer::newTerminalConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "someone connected ...";
    std::cout << "someone connected ..." << std::endl;
    QTcpSocket *socket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    liveConnections.push_back(socket);
}

superServer::superServer(QObject *parent)  :
    QObject(parent)
{
    tcpServer = new QTcpServer();

    if(!tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9889))
        qDebug() << "Server could not start";
    else
        qDebug() << "Server started!";

    connect(tcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newTerminalConnection()));
    connect(tcpServer, SIGNAL(acceptError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(errorconnecting(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
}

void superServer::errorconnecting(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)
{
    qDebug() << "error connecting to client";
}
```

Also, I am connecting like this:

```
void tradeView::doConnect()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()),this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)),this, SLOT(bytesWritten(qint64)));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readyRead()));

    qDebug() << "connecting...";

    // this is not a blocking call
    socket->connectToHost("localhost", 9889);

    // we need to wait...
    if(!socket->waitForConnected(5000))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: " << socket->errorString();
    }
}

void tradeView::connected()
{
    qDebug() << "connected...";
}

void tradeView::disconnected()
{
    qDebug() << "disconnected...";
}

void tradeView::bytesWritten(qint64 bytes)
{
    qDebug() << bytes << " bytes written...";
}
```

The client connects !!! Even Telnet works !!!

But that signal does not get emitted. Can you please tell me what is wrong ?

Trust me I have looked at more than a dozen related threads here on SO and qt-center etc. None give a solution. 
Please help.

Comment: are you sure there's no other program listening at port 9889? Stop your server and check is there's someone listening

Comment: Are you sure there is an event loop running?

Comment: No, no other program was listening to 9889. Also, Event loop is definitely running.